# Why does my smart device app create a *.asmmeta.dll file?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, windows-mobile, compact-framework, smartphone

My compact framework application is generating a ...asmmeta.dll file in the output folder.  What exactly are these files and why are they created?  I have made compact framework applications in the past and it hasn't created any files like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason (you've not said a lot about what you're building) may be that you have USerControls or custom controls of some sort.  In that case, the asmeta files are created for Studio designer support of those controls.  Do you also have an XMTA file in the project?